# Monadic do notation inside let, is it possible?

Tags: haskell, let, do-notation

Consider the following valid Haskell code

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = f
  print x

f :: Maybe (Int, Int)
f =
  Just 3 >>= (\a ->
    Just 5 >>= (\b ->
      return (a, b)))
```

where the function `f` can be rewritten equivalently with do-notation like this

```
f :: Maybe (Int, Int)
f = do
  a <- Just 3
  b <- Just 5
  return (a, b)
```

What annoys me, the do notation won't work when I put the contents of `f` inline. The following code does not even parse:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = do
    a <- Just 3
    b <- Just 5
    return (a, b)
  print x
```

Am I correct that inside `let` I am forced to resort to `(>>=)`?

While I'm at it, the following code does not parse, either:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x =
    Just 3 >>= (\a ->
      Just 5 >>= (\b ->
        return (a, b)))
  print x
```

I don't see an obvious reason other than an unnecessary limited power of `let`. Is there an elegant way to use `bind` inside `let`?

Comment: Mind you do not write `in`...

Comment: This is clearly an indentation problem, but I'm not a sufficiently powerful indentation master to answer it without GHC in front of me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Am I correct that inside `let` I am forced to resort to `(>>=)`?

No:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = do
      a <- Just 3
      b <- Just 5
      return (a, b)
  print x
```

Haskell's [layout](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-17800010.3) rule dictates that the body of the binding `e` in `p = e` mus be intended at least as much as the beginning of `p` (or the first binding, if you're using multiple at once). Since `let` in `do` follows (almost) the same rules as `let … in`, you can verify this with the following function:

```
f :: Int
f = 
  let x =
    3 + 5
  in x
```

This doesn't work, since `3 + 5` doesn't have the same or greater indentation level as `x`. However,

```
f :: Int
f =
  let x =
       3 + 5
  in x
```

works. Also, while the `main` above works, it doesn't really convey that `a` and `b` are things in `x`'s `do` block, so it's a little bit better to indent them slightly more:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = do
        a <- Just 3
        b <- Just 5
        return (a, b)
  print x
```

Comment: I much prefer to lift `let`s out of `do` blocks whenever possible. `let x = ... in print x`.

Comment: @dfeuer: Which is the default translation according to [3.14](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14).

Comment: Oh, I know it does the same thing; I just prefer to pull out any `let`s that don't depend on the results of monadic actions, to make their independence visually obvious.

Comment: It’s also possible to avoid having to align things like this by just putting a newline+indent after `let`, same as any other layout keyword like `do`, `of`, or `where`.